# Картинка фоном в div

Tags: vue.js, stylus, sylius

Имеется компонент vue со следующим содержимом:

```
<template lang="html">
 <div class="logo"></div>
</template>

<script> 
</script>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
.logo
  width 50px
  height 50px
  background-image url('../assets/logo.png')
</style>
```

структура папок стандартная. Т.е та, что образуется при установке webpack-simple. Как итог работы - ошибка!

Говорит:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../assets/logo_with.png'

Понимаю, что можно в верстке указать урл. Но нужно тут. Искал в гугле, он мне выдал, что это возможно, но не факт, в настройках путей в вэбпаке - пробовал, не получилось.

Потом он мне не раз говорил, что путь нужен /dist/и тут несколько вариантов/logo.png - тоже не работает.

Потом вообще наткнулся на форуме vue, что мол это действо по какой-то неведомой причине не было включено в возможность vue. Дата публикации такого комента, а это был комент на туже проблему, примерно две недели назад от публикации этого вопроса. Но есть сомнение в авторе комента.

Так вот вопрос, кто-нибудь пробовал ставить фоном картинку и пути прописывать не в шаблоне, а в стилях?

P.S. вэбпак не выкладываю, он стандартен, тот что при развертывании шаблона.

Comment: Посмотрите описание лоадера, там описано как он с путями работает: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ru/configurations/asset-url.html

Comment: Ну да, а еще там сказано следующее: Так как .png это не JavaScript-файл, вам необходимо настроить Webpack использовать file-loader или url-loader для их обработки. Проект создаваемый с помощью vue-cli уже сделает это за вас.  Тут последнее предложение важно))

Comment: Вот так пробовали `url('./assets/logo.png')`?

Comment: угу)) и так и не так пробовал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело вот в чем! При создании вопроса я забыл указать одну очень немаловажную деталь. А именно то, что в проекте еще присутсвует сервер на эксперссе.

И именно там и была ошибка.